# How to handle complex tree array and traverse new arrays?

Tags: javascript, json

*Object index 0:*

If `select===1`, the third-level array length have two `select===1`, the two-level push to `selected:[8,9]` and `checkedAll:true`
the one-level `checkedAll:true` and push to `selected:[7]`

*Object index 1:* Same as above Object index 0

*Object index 2:*

If `select===1`, the two-level push to `selected:[15]`, the third-level `child` array length `>` two-level array `selected` length, `indeterminate:true`
and the one-level `indeterminate:true`

I am trying to solve the complex json, don't know how to implement the following result array.

**The correct result is printed as follows**

```
[{
        "id": 1,
        "pid": 0,
        "name": "a",
        "select": 0,
        "checkedAll": true,
        "indeterminate": false,
        "selected": [7],
        "child": [{
          "id": 7,
          "pid": 1,
          "name": "a-1",
          "select": 1,
          "checkedAll": true,
          "indeterminate": false,
          "selected": [8, 9],
          "child": [{
              "id": 8,
              "pid": 7,
              "name": "a-1-2",
              "select": 1
            },
            {
              "id": 9,
              "pid": 7,
              "name": "a-2-2",
              "select": 1
            }
          ]
        }]
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "pid": 0,
        "name": "b",
        "select": 1,
        "checkedAll": true,
        "indeterminate": false,
        "selected": [10],
        "child": [{
          "id": 10,
          "pid": 2,
          "name": "b-1",
          "select": 1,
          "checkedAll": true,
          "indeterminate": false,
          "selected": [11, 12],
          "child": [{
              "id": 11,
              "pid": 10,
              "name": "b-1-1",
              "select": 1
            },
            {
              "id": 12,
              "pid": 10,
              "name": "b-1-2",
              "select": 1
            }
          ]
        }]
      },

      {
        "id": 3,
        "pid": 0,
        "name": "c",
        "select": 0,
        "checkedAll": false,
        "indeterminate": true,
        "selected": [],
        "child": [{
          "id": 13,
          "pid": 3,
          "name": "c-1",
          "select": 1,
          "checkedAll": false,
          "indeterminate": true,
          "selected": [15],
          "child": [{
              "id": 14,
              "pid": 13,
              "name": "c-1-1",
              "select": 0
            },
            {
              "id": 15,
              "pid": 13,
              "name": "c-1-2",
              "select": 1
            }
          ]
        }]
      }

    ]
```

*My code:*

```js
var result = [{
    "id": 1,
    "pid": 0,
    "name": "a",
    "select": 0,
    "child": [{
      "id": 7,
      "pid": 1,
      "name": "a-1",
      "select": 1,
      "child": [{
          "id": 8,
          "pid": 7,
          "name": "a-1-2",
          "select": 1
        },
        {
          "id": 9,
          "pid": 7,
          "name": "a-2-2",
          "select": 1
        }
      ]
    }]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "pid": 0,
    "name": "b",
    "select": 0,
    "child": [{
      "id": 10,
      "pid": 2,
      "name": "b-1",
      "select": 0,
      "child": [{
          "id": 11,
          "pid": 10,
          "name": "b-1-1",
          "select": 1
        },
        {
          "id": 12,
          "pid": 10,
          "name": "b-1-2",
          "select": 1
        }
      ]
    }]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "pid": 0,
    "name": "c",
    "select": 0,
    "child": [{
      "id": 13,
      "pid": 3,
      "name": "c-1",
      "select": 1,
      "child": [{
          "id": 14,
          "pid": 13,
          "name": "c-1-1",
          "select": 0
        },
        {
          "id": 15,
          "pid": 13,
          "name": "c-1-2",
          "select": 1
        }
      ]
    }]
  }
]

var selected = []
for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
  const a1 = result[i].child

  for (let j = 0; j < a1.length; j++) {
    console.log(a1[j].name)

    const a2 = a1[j].child

    for (let k = 0; k < a2.length; k++) {

      if (a1[j].id === a2[k].pid) {
        if (a2[k].select === 1) {
          console.log(a1[j].id)
          console.log(a2[k].name)

          console.log('yyyyyyyy', a2[k].id)

        }
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log(result)
```

**described as follows**
[image]

[image]

Comment: The question is unclear, can you try to explain better what you're trying to do?

Comment: And show what you have tried to solve your issue

Comment: The picture has instructions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And what about this (not sure if it is possible to change items order), you can click accept under voting arrows in case you like it:

```js
var selected = [], result = input();
for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    const a1 = result[i].child

    for (let j = 0; j < a1.length; j++) {

        const a2 = a1[j].child

        for (let k = 0; k < a2.length; k++) {

            if (a1[j].id === a2[k].pid) {
                if (a2[k].select === 1) {
                    let selected = a1[j].selected || [];
                    selected.push(a2[k].id)
                    a1[j].selected = selected;
                    if (selected.length == a2.length) {
                        result[i].checkedAll = true;
                        a1[j].checkedAll = true;
                    }
                    result[i].selected = a1[j].id;
                }
            }
        }
        result[i].indeterminate = !result[i].checkedAll;
        a1[j].indeterminate = !a1[j].checkedAll;
    }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2))

function input() {
    return [{
        "id": 1,
        "pid": 0,
        "name": "a",
        "select": 0,
        "child": [{
            "id": 7,
            "pid": 1,
            "name": "a-1",
            "select": 1,
            "child": [{
                "id": 8,
                "pid": 7,
                "name": "a-1-2",
                "select": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 9,
                "pid": 7,
                "name": "a-2-2",
                "select": 1
            }
            ]
        }]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "pid": 0,
        "name": "b",
        "select": 0,
        "child": [{
            "id": 10,
            "pid": 2,
            "name": "b-1",
            "select": 0,
            "child": [{
                "id": 11,
                "pid": 10,
                "name": "b-1-1",
                "select": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 12,
                "pid": 10,
                "name": "b-1-2",
                "select": 1
            }
            ]
        }]
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "pid": 0,
        "name": "c",
        "select": 0,
        "child": [{
            "id": 13,
            "pid": 3,
            "name": "c-1",
            "select": 1,
            "child": [{
                "id": 14,
                "pid": 13,
                "name": "c-1-1",
                "select": 0
            },
            {
                "id": 15,
                "pid": 13,
                "name": "c-1-2",
                "select": 1
            }
            ]
        }]
    }
    ];
}
```